# Compile or install HariSekhon/Nagios-Plugins on ARM

Tags: arm, nagios

Has anyone been able to install https://github.com/HariSekhon/Nagios-Plugins on ARM-based machines? I am looking to install them on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS running on aarch64 architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've bypassed ARM by enabling emulation and running this in a docker image with x86 emulation...